# Changing the key binding for Command Palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

How does one change the key binding for the Command Palette in Visual Studio Code? It's not showing up in Keyboard Shortcuts, and searches of the Internet generally and SO specifically aren't providing an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The reason I couldn't find it is because it appears in Keyboard Shortcuts as "Show All Commands" rather than "Command Palette."

Comment: One way of finding it would be inputting the keybinding in the Keyboard Shortcuts search area, after selecting the "Recording Keys" icon to the right.  Only two possibilities for Ctrl+Shift+P : the other easily eliminated.

Answer (score 3):

In cases where you aren't sure of the command, one way of finding it would be inputting the keybinding in the Keyboard Shortcuts search area, after selecting the "Recording Keys" icon to the right.

Only two possibilities exist for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> : one easily eliminated.

Especially since there is no "when" clause for the "Show All Commands" command - so it must be available everywhere, like you would expect the Command Palette to be.

In this way, you can at least reduce the possibilities.

[image: demo of keybindings Recording Keys]