# Change shortcut for opening Command Palette in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I change the keyboard shortcut for opening the Command Palette in VSCode? The default (on macOS) is Shift+Command+P, which I don't like. I want to change it to something else.

I know how to change keyboard shortcuts in general, but there doesn't seem to be an option to change the shortcut for opening the command palette - or at least I can't find it when searching for "command palette". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is the info you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444767/836330.  It is the `Show All Commands` command that you want to rebind.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! That's the solution, so if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is really a duplicate of that same question.  I would always appreciate an upvote there though.

Answer (score 2):

You configure keyboard shortcuts for VS Code via *File | Preferences | Keyboard Shortcuts*.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor for more information.

If you know the current shortcut, you can search for it. For example:

[image]

In this case you can see the command name is "Show All Commands". You can then edit it directly.